# Endianness on reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, endianness, reinterpret-cast, uint16

I have a pointer to an uint8_t aray. Each 2 elements are actually a uint_16_t value and I want to use `reinterpret_cast` :

`uint16_t *Dst16Rgb = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(Dst8Rgb);`

The output has the wrong endianness, is there a way to specify `reinterpret_cast` if I want to do it on little or big endian?

Thanks!

Comment: Short answer: No.  Long answer, really depends on what you start with on how to change the endianness.

Comment: When you use `reinterpret_cast` all you do is tell the compiler "pretend that the type of the expression is really something else". It's a better C-style cast, and it doesn't really do anything at all at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

> I have a pointer to an uint8_t aray. Each 2 elements are actually a uint_16_t

Either you actually have an array of `uint8_t`, or you actually have an array of `uint_16_t`. It cannot be both.

> ```
> uint16_t *Dst16Rgb = reinterpret_cast<uint16_t*>(Dst8Rgb);
> ```

Indirecting through the reinterpret pointer will have undefined behaviour since there is no `uint16_t` object at the pointed address.

Even if you disable strict aliasing, there is still UB unless you guarantee that the byte array is sufficiently aligned for `uint_16_t`.

> is there a way to specify reinterpret_cast if I want to do it on little or big endian?

No. Data is always reintepreted in native endianness. If the input bytes have different endianness, then the result will be "wrong".

You must know the endianness of the input data. You can read bytes as a multi-byte integer without knowing the native endianness by shifting and masking.